# Automating Xamarin.Forms UI Tests with Ranorex

Tags: android, ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, ranorex

Has anyone used Ranorex to test Forms UI's? I don't see any UI id properties that I could set from the View/Element class so I was wondering if I can set automation id's through the Forms objects. One option would be to wrap all Forms views around custom renderers and expose an ID field but that isn't an ideal solution for obvious reasons.

For iOS the method that works for Xamarin Cloud also works well with Ranorex. It doesn't work on Android though so that is still an open issue.

http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/uitest-and-test-cloud/

```
Forms.ViewInitialized += (object sender, ViewInitializedEventArgs e) => {
    // http://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/testcloud/set-accessibilityidentifier-ios/
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(e.View.StyleId)) {
        e.NativeView.AccessibilityIdentifier = e.View.StyleId;
    }
};
```